# Spark 2.0.0 - parquet read empty table

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, parquet, sparkr

I just updated to `Spark 2.0.0` and I want to read my parquet files in `SparkR`:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"), sparkPackages = "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.0")

df1 <- read.parquet("my.parquet")
```

But the `SparkDataFrame` returns empty. When I collect it, I get my variables/columns, but no rows. Yet, this code works fine for `parquet` I generated with `Spark 1.6.2`.

This parquet file was produced in another file.scala and `Spark 2.0.0`:

```
myDf.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite")
.option("header", "true")
.option("parquet.enable.summary-metadata","true").save("my.parquet")
```

From the [Release Notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html), "When writing Parquet files, the summary files are not written by default. To re-enable it, users must set `“parquet.enable.summary-metadata”` to `true.`", which I did.

myDf is not empty, as I can print it out with `show()`, and files are created normally by the write:

```
./_common_metadata
./_metadata
./_SUCCESS
./part-r-00000-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00001-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00002-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00003-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00004-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00005-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00006-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00007-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00008-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00009-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00010-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00011-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00012-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00013-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00014-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00015-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00016-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00017-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00018-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00019-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00020-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00021-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00022-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00023-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00024-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00025-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00026-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00027-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00028-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
./part-r-00029-6235ae25-fb7b-472b-9f0e-139907759393.snappy.parquet
```

Either myDF is written correctly but not loaded correctly, or it is not written correctly. Any insight on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed not writing the parquet correctly.

I was running my job with `--packages "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0"` in the command line. However, now `spark-csv` is included in `Spark 2.0.0`, AND I was calling the wrong version of it. Removing the packages command fixed it.